# Fastapi pydantic related schema response to be filtered by column

Tags: foreign-keys, fastapi, pydantic

I am using fastapi pydantic schema for get request apis to invoice and its corresponding items. The api is working fine but considering all the related rows of items with invoice_id. But I want the foreign key related data to be filtered based on some column. Like where `is_active == True`, consider only those invoice item rows.

```
{
   'id': 1
   'invoice_number': 1
   'item_name': 'this is invoice one'
   'invoice_items': [
      {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': item one, deleted_at: None},
      {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': item two, deleted_at: None},
      {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': item three, deleted_at: None}
   ]
}
```

Comment: What does your actual SQL model and query look like? That's where this is going to happen, not in the Pydantic schema.

Comment: class InvoiceItemSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    invoice_id: int
    item_name: str
    item_description: str
    cost: float
    quantity: int
    price: float
    deleted_at: date = None

class InvoiceSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    invoice_number: int
    invoice_description: str
    total: float
    invoice_items: List[InvoiceItemSchema]

Comment: Please add information like that _to your question_ and properly format it, instead of it being garbled as comments. Also, that is only your Pydantic schema - it does not have anything to do with how and what you're fetching from the database.

Comment: I am not querying there, just dumping data in invoice_schema.

Comment: invoice_items: List[InvoiceItemSchema] where is_active == true (something like this)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon your question.

You shouldn't do that filtering in pydantic schema.
You can filter data before you give that data to response.
You can do something like this after you got information from your database:

```
invoice = {
    'id': 1,
    'invoice_number': 1,
    'item_name': 'this is invoice one',
    'invoice_items': [
        {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item one', 'is_active': True},
        {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item two', 'is_active': False},
        {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item three', 'is_active': True},
    ]
}

invoice_items = invoice.invoice_items

filtered_invoice_items = [
    inv_itm 
    for inv_itm in invoice_items 
    if inv_itm.is_active is True
]

invoice.invoice_items = filtered_invoice_items
```

then your invoice will look like this and you can give that `invoice` as response:

```
invoice = {
    'id': 1,
    'invoice_number': 1,
    'item_name': 'this is invoice one',
    'invoice_items': [
        {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item one', 'is_active': True},
        {'invoice_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item three', 'is_active': True},
    ]
}
```

I hope this advice will be helpful for you.
Wish you good luck!